# How to convert the where match query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert the following query to Laravel ORM

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM snippets WHERE MATCH(snippets_name,seo_description,snippets_description,snippet_tags) 
          AGAINST (' ".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT " . $start . "," . $limit;
```

I tried following code

But Not getting the desired results

```
 $searchdata = DB::table('snippets')
        ->selectRaw("*")
        ->whereRaw("MATCH(snippets_name,seo_description,snippets_description,snippet_tags) AGAINST (' ".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
        ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: can you plz share your datatable structure?

Comment: this query is working awesome - $sql = "SELECT * FROM snippets WHERE MATCH(snippets_name,seo_description,snippets_description,snippet_tags) 
          AGAINST (' ".$query."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT " . $start . "," . $limit;

Answer (score 0):

What results are you actually getting?

I've implemented FULLTEXT search using Eloquent before, and recommend moving the `MATCH` clause into the SELECT, and ordering by the score it returns.

Additionally, `paginate()` doesn't work so well with raw query parts, so you might be better off creating your own pagination using `take()` (limit) and `skip()` (offset).

And, finally, you should use a prepared query binding rather than adding your `$query` variable into the raw SQL.

This might work for you:

```
\DB::table('snippets')
    ->select([
        '*',
        \DB::raw("MATCH(snippets_name, seo_description, snippets_description, snippet_tags) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score"),
    ])
    ->take($limit)
    ->skip($start)
    ->havingRaw('score > 0')
    ->orderBy('score', 'DESC')
    ->setBindings([$query])
    ->get();
```

I've included the `havingRaw()` to exclude any results with a 0 score, which are probably irrelevant.